# In Magento 2.2.5, Login link is displaying even customer loggedIn

Tags: customer, login, magento-2.2.5

In Magento 2.2.5, I am checking the customer is logged in or not in order to display the login link in case if he is not logged in. If he is logged In means I need to display the My Account link.

When I am trying to login, it is logging in correctly and when navigating to other page, In header menu it is showing the Login even after login.

Any solution for this.

Note:
I have disabled page cache in backend.

Comment: Are you using customized theme? You should use KnockoutJS and Html template to display login state of the customer. That will work with FPC.

Comment: I have customized luma theme. Can you share the code.

Answer (score 0):

somewhere file .phtml

> $customerSession =
> $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
>
> if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {    //do something here... }

Comment: I used this code only. But it is still showing the login link only even after loggedIn.